# How to change color of a column in RDLC report?

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting, rdlc

I am using RDLC reports in asp.net.

I am getting numerical data e.g.

```
7000,
6000,
8000,
9000
```

in a particular column i.e. `BidPrice` and it's expression `=CDec(Fields!BidPrice.Value)

`Now upon loading RDLC report it should show the lowest value being highlighted in RED color i.e. 6000 should be highlighted in red or any other lowest value after it.

I can't find any color function etc so please help.

Update: I did this but it shows the largest number in Red.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost each property of your report items can be an expression. In your case you need to use an expression for placeholder properties of table cell.

Walk-through is for Report Builder but same code applies to every designer you use.

· Double click table placeholder to open its properties.
· Select **Font** section.
· Click on **fx** button near **Color** combo box.
· Replace existing constant expression with

```
=Iif(Min(Fields!BidPrice.Value, "DataSet1") = Fields!BidPrice.Value, "Red", "Black")
```

Don't forget to replace `Dataset1` with your dataset's name.
· Close all dialogs confirming with **OK**.

You have the same property available also in the property grid (where you may also change background color, for example to have white text on red background).

Example:

[image: Report Builder screenshot example]

**Explanation**:

`Iif` returns its second argument if expression of first argument evaluates to true and third argument otherwise. We use it to select one color according to an expression.

Now we have to **find minimum value**, we can use an aggregate function over entire dataset (`Fields!BidPrice.Value` always evaluates for *current* record then `Min(Fields!BidPrice.Value) = Fields!BidPrice.Value` is always `true`). Syntax is straightforward: `Min(Fields!BidPrice.Value, "DataSet1")` finds minimum in whole set of data.

Expression returns `"Red"` constant for values that equal to minimum (even multiple ones) and `"Black"` for the others. More complex expressions may be combined (for example to alaso highlight in green maximum value).

Comment: thanks a lot sir, but I am completely new and not picking that what should I put in Column expression box ? I got the color FX part but not the last

Comment: If you mean "where should I write that expression": in the big text box that opens when you click "fx" button. Don't forget that, from property grid on the right, you may apply this (or another) expression also to background color property (for example to have a green background and white text). Expression to write is the highlighted one (now moved to its own line for clarity)

Comment: Ok sir, please lemme try. Be here sir

Comment: Sir I tried, it changed color but it also shows all the values same, i.e. 6000 6000 6000 6000 

.other values disappeared. Each row shows same value (Minimum one)

Comment: I went to BidPrice TEXTBOX properties, clicked FONT, click FX near color and put Iif(Min(Fields!BidPrice.Value, "DataSetBids") = Fields!BidPrice.Value, "Red", "Black")

Comment: then went to BidPrice Expression and put Min(Fields!BidPrice.Value, "DataSetBids")

Comment: No, for color you have also to include "=" at beginning of your expression (see code). For column you don't need to have Min() otherwise it'll always display minimum value...

Comment: Sir I did but now it shows the largest number in red. See my updated post, I posted screen shot

Comment: Largest one? What's the type (on DB) of that field?

Comment: thanks sir done, Actually i was converting to decimal in expression but i removed that and it worked